# \chapter command in REVTeX 4.1

Tags: chapters, revtex

I'm currently writing my Bachelor's thesis in LaTeX using the REVTeX 4.1 document class (`revtex4-1` package). I am using this package because of the clear citation style and nice figure caption layout. I would like to have my thesis consist of multiple chapters, e.g. 'Introduction', 'Theory' etc. However, it appears that REVTeX 4.1 does not support the `\chapter` command, because my chapter title is not typeset when I use this command.

Is there any way in which to include or 'emulate' a chapter title above the different parts of my thesis?

Here is some code that I would naïvely use to achieve what I want.

```
\documentclass[aps, prb, preprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize},format=plain,labelfont={bf},up,up,]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fullpage,graphicx,textcomp,gensymb,wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Theory}

\section{Introduction to Scanning Tunneling Microscopy}

(text of my chapter)

\end{document}
```

Note: Ideally, I would like to create one big file using `\include` that includes all the separate `.tex` files that are my individual chapters. I don't know if this has any influence on the fact that I want to use the `\chapter` command within the `revtex4-1` document class, but I want to mention it anyway.

EDIT: I was thinking of maybe using a package like `titlesec` to artificially create a heading that resembles a chapter heading, but so far I haven't managed to make it work. The code that I was thinking of is (right below \begin{document} in the above code):

```
\titleclass{\chapterthesis}{top}[\part]
\newcounter{chapterthesis}
\providecommand{\chaptert}{\alph{chapterthesis}}
\titleformat{\chaptert}[display]{bf}{experimental}{3pt}{\chaptert}

\chaptert{Theory}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: The `revtex` class doesn't support chapters, because it's meant for submitting articles to journals about physics.

Comment: @egreg: I am aware of that, and that is the reason I have made this post. In writing my thesis I would like to combine the features of the RevTex package with the structure of, say, a book.

Comment: Adding all the necessary infrastructure for chapters would be a rather complex task.

Comment: As mentioned by others, I'd recommend not using `revtex4` for projects other than what it is intended for.

Comment: And there is no way of using a package like titlesec to artificially include a section heading that resembles a chapter heading? I'm exploring that option now, but I haven't managed to make it work. Examplary code:

Comment: @Koen the thing is that you will need many adjustments; off the top of my head, you have to make provision for marks for headers, define how new entries will be typeset in the ToC, subordinate some counters (equation, figure, table) to the chapter counter. I agree with others: the work involved is not worthy; it would be better to choose another document class designed for typesetting chapters.

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone for the replies, I'll look into using another document class.

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Since a lot of people probably get introduced into LaTeX in submitting articles, many others might have the same question as well. As such, it would be nice if someone could point towards something to use, instead of simply stating that it cannot be done.

Answer (score 3):

To sum up the comments: like a lot of classes intended for submission to journals, REVTeX is really not suited to tasks other than that for which it was written. It makes lots of internal changes and assumptions that are entirely reasonable for its purpose, and one of those is 'no chapters'. As such, the correct solution is to use an alternative class and load packages which add the desired functionality.